# Segmentation fault when I try to read values with preallocated matrix passed by reference in a function

Tags: c, dynamic, segmentation-fault, malloc, pass-by-reference

The function has two arguments: a char pointer and an integer triple pointer.
The integer triple pointer is used to pass by reference an integer double pointer (in order to allocate a matrix).

I have already debugged and all goes straigth until the second iteration of the for loop used to acquire the number from file.

```
void leggimatrice(char *filename, int ***mat)
{
    int counter = 0, i, j, ap;
    FILE *fp;

    //count how many numbers there are in the file
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL) {
        while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &i) != EOF)
            counter++;
        fclose(fp);
    }
    //allocate the matrix; the value of counter is 9
    *mat = malloc(sizeof(int *) * sqrt(counter))
        for (i = 0; i < sqrt(counter); i++) {
        (*mat)[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * sqrt(counter));
    }

    //reopen the file and save the values in the allocated matrix
    fp = fopen("matrice.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < sqrt(counter); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sqrt(counter); j++)
            fscanf(fp, "%d", (mat[i])[j]);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return;
}
```

The result is a segmentation fault that appears during the second iteration of the first for loop (i=1)

Comment: You could simplify things a bit - instead of a three-star parameter, just have the function return a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: `(mat[i])[j]` Should that be `(*mat)[i][j]`?

Comment: Also, what if `√counter` does not produce an integer? You will lose data. And another thing, the number of rows and columns is lost after the function ends. How will you use the matrix later without that data?

Comment: I knowh that there are solutions simpler, but I want to use this solution to improve my pointer knoledge.

Comment: (mat[i])[j] Should that be (*mat)[i][j] no because fscanf wants the pointer of the variable. The parenthesis that I put I think that are not necessary.

Comment: This question would benefit from https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- as is, it can't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL) {
...
fp = fopen("matrice.txt", "r");
```

These aren't necessarily opening the same file, so (unless `filename == "matrice.txt"`) you may be counting and reading different files.

The real cause of `SIGSEGV` is here:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", (mat[i])[j]);
```

It should be:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", &(*mat)[i][j]);
```

or equivalently:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", (*mat)[i] + j);
```